# Unable to display image file in Jupyter markdown cell in vscode or pycharm?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm, markdown, jupyter

This code in a Markdown cell:

```
<img src="images/grad_summary.png" style="width:600px;height:300px;">
```

works fine in Jupyter browser, but in VS Code and pycharm with Python extension it does not render at all, only a blank image box is shown. Both are running in the same conda environment.

This alternate method in a Markdown cell:

```
![title](images/grad_summary.png)
```

also works fine in Jupyter browser but does not render in VS Code with Python ext.

I searched stack overflow, there was something close but it did not address this issue. Any insights appreciated.

[vocode broken image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBjbx.png)

Comment: Did you try to mentioned fully qualified path of image rather than relative path? This is to isolate the issue of not being able to locate the image through vs code or pycharm

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. I have placed the image in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

We actually have an issue already reported with loading and showing local images. If you want to track our progress on fixing this issue you can follow our github issue here.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7704