# Unable to display images in markdown cells of VSCode Jupyter notebook on WSL2 remote

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm using VSCode Jupyter Notebook functionality while running it in the Windows 10 WSL2 remote on Ubuntu 20.04.

When I'm trying to display an image in the Markdown cell using

```markdown
![title](image.png)
```

or

```html
<img src="image.png">
```

no image is displayed. What should I configure to the image appear in the notebook?

I've searched SO and have found a few topics discussing it, i.e.

- [Unable to display image file in Jupyter markdown cell in vscode or pycharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58818053/unable-to-display-image-file-in-jupyter-markdown-cell-in-vscode-or-pycharm)
- [can not render images in ipynb files on vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58862684/can-not-render-images-in-ipynb-files-on-vscode)
- [How to attach an image in Jupyter Notebook without keeping the file in the same directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73596358/how-to-attach-an-image-in-jupyter-notebook-without-keeping-the-file-in-the-same/)

All of them suggest that the problem should be fixed by the VSCode team. And even for me the images are displayed *if I create the notebook in native Windows 10 VSCode*. The problem still persists on WSL2 Ubuntu remote.

My configuration is

```
WSL version: 1.2.5.0
Kernel version: 5.15.90.1
WSLg version: 1.0.51
MSRDC version: 1.2.3770
Direct3D version: 1.608.2-61064218
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.19045.2965

Ubuntu 20.04

Version: 1.81.1 (user setup)
Commit: 6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794
Date: 2023-08-09T22:22:42.175Z
Electron: 22.3.18
ElectronBuildId: 22689846
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
```